# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data -SvelteKit

Tags: json, go, fetch, sveltekit

I am running Sveltekit and my Golang server on the same machine `localhost` (I have enabled `mode: 'no-cors',`). when i was creating **post fetch** to the server i was unable to get the json response . For some reason browser console showing
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` in Firefox and
`+page.svelte? [sm]:312 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at +page.svelte? [sm]:312:33) at +page.svelte? [sm]:312:33` in Chrome

But If i send request to a `+server.ts` file than send the same request to the golang server it works file . it gives the desired response ,

i have use the same fetch request code before `@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.405` . it was working fine . For some reason don't know why in the latest version of svelte kit it is not working

My fetch request (from +page.svelte) :

##### +page.svelte

```
async function PostGameData() {
        await fetch('http://localhost:8001/admin/addproduct', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Accept: 'application/json' }),
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((d) => {
                console.log(' ~ file: +page.svelte ~ line 312 ~ .then ~ Response', d);
            });
    }
```

From Golang Server :

#### main.go

```
func(H *DatabaseCollections) AdminAddProduct() gin.HandlerFunc {
  return func(c * gin.Context) {
    c.Request.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        var req GameData err
        : = c.Bind(&req) if err !=
            nil{
    log.Println("Error : ", err)}

            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"ok" : " accepted bro"})
  }
}
```

#### Output :

after calling **PostGameData()**

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` in Firefox and `+page.svelte? [sm]:312 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at +page.svelte? [sm]:312:33) at +page.svelte? [sm]:312:33` in Chrome

### But

if i send the request to **+server.ts** and then make the same fetch to the Golang server than the output was as expected

#### +server.ts

```
export async function POST({ request }) {
    const data = await request.json();
    let resData
    await fetch('http://localhost:8001/admin/addproduct', {
            // credentials: 'same-origin',
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Accept: 'application/json' }),

            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((d) => {
                resData=data
                console.log(' ~ file: +page.svelte ~ line 312 ~ .then ~ REsponse', d);
        });

    return json(resData)
}
```

#### +page.svelte

```
async function PostGameData() {
        await fetch('/api/addgame', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Accept: 'application/json' }),
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((d) => {
                console.log(' ~ file: +page.svelte ~ line 312 ~ .then ~ Response', d);
            });
    }
```

#### Output:

```
{
    "ok": " accepted bro"
}
```

I tried all the solution about this topic in Stackoverflow, but None worked for me . I desperately need a solution .

Comment: Did you try to change in your go coding  `c.Bind` into `c.ShouldBindJSON` ?

Comment: @faschulze  yes i tried every way in Gin framework and also tried without any Go framework , just using std library . Same error . i don't think it's a golang issue . may be i am missing something in sveltekit

Comment: did you checked what is the status code coming from your backend service before doing response.json().
it seems in golang case it is not a json.
Also try checking if your c.Bind is working properly or not

Comment: @SmritiShikha respone status code is fine (200) . I don't think it's c.Bind() problem i also tried with standard library . it's same ,   just  try out your self ,  In sveltekit from +page.svelte  send POST request to golang server(with or without framework) and give a json response